# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not calling callback functions

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please tell me why this code is not working in Chrome? (I read about Firefox bug and tried all proposed solutions) 
User is asked if they wish to allow.....this works and they click yes.....but the callback functions are never called...i thought adding the timeout would work but no luck.  Ive tested on cellphone & desktop and same failure.

Please help!!

```
window.onload = getMyLocation;

function getMyLocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayError, {timeout:5000});
    }else{
        alert("Brower does not support Geolocation");
    }
}

function displayError(error){
    var errorTypes={
        0:"Unknown Error",
        1:"Permission Denied by User",
        2:"Position is not Available",      
        3:"Request Timed Out"
    }
    var errorMessage=errorTypes[error.code];
    if (error.code==0 || error.code==2){
        errorMessage=errorMessage + " " + error.message;
    }

    var div = getElementById("location");
    div.innerHTML=errorMessage
}

function displayLocation(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var div = getElementById("location");
    div.innerHTML="latitude:" + latitude + " longitude:" + longitude;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = getElementById("location");
```

=>  `var div = document.getElementById("location");`

and you miss some semicolon:

```
div.innerHTML=errorMessage;

var errorTypes={
    0:"Unknown Error",
    1:"Permission Denied by User",
    2:"Position is not Available",      
    3:"Request Timed Out"
};
```

Hope this help! :)